# Convention for chain of inequalities

Tags: inequality, convention

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask. In the proof of a theorem, I basically want to write $A<B$, and $B=C$, thus $A<C$ as a chain of inequalities. I am not sure if there is a convention to do so: shall I write
\begin{align*}
A & < B \\
& = C
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
A & < B \\
& < C
\end{align*}?

In other words, does the second row of the chain refer to the relationship between $A$ and $C$, or to the relationship between $B$ and $C$? I would prefer not repeating $A$ because it is a long expression in my case.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second row would be understood to refer to the relationship between $B$ and $C$, so \begin{align*}A&<B\\     &=C\end{align*} would be the proper way of writing this.

Comment: Great. Many thanks!